# How to replace specific strings with spaces on sides into text file if it is merged with text

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to replace specific strings in text document, if it is written there merged with other text

for example document content is:

```
a1some textb2
some c2c1text a1
c1 some text c2d2
some textd2
```

I want get this result:

```
a1 some text b2
some c2 c1 text a1
c1 some text c2 d2
some text d2
```

So seems like it is a wrong way:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(path); 
       text = text.Replace("a1", " a1 ").Replace("b2", " b2 ")
                  .Replace("c1", " c1 ").Replace("d2", " d2 ");
File.WriteAllText(path, text);
```

Because in result I have something like this:

```
 a1   
   some text               b2
    some           c2           c1 text                a1
    c1 some text      c2              d2
    some text                d2
```

Comment: It works as expected (Not as you posted).  what is your problem?

Comment: @L.B yes and works well if I just change something but with spaces I got this result, and can't get why, there is nothing to do this

Comment: DefColin `I have something like this:` But I can not get this garbage when I run your code...

Comment: Are you sure you do not manipulate the text in the file somewhere else also? Can you post the entire code in the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this Regex:

```
\s?(a1|b2|c1|d2)\s?
```

Here is how to do it in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = @"a1some textb2";
        var pattern = @"\s?(a1|b2|c1|d2)\s?";
        var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, " $1 ");

        Console.WriteLine(replaced);

    }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xf0BVO

Comment: What doesn't work in the question and how does this answer fix it?

Comment: @L.B it seems to me that the "spaces" is what causing the problem in his question. I think the optionality space with regex will fix his output.

Comment: @Ibrahim Hello, this way not really useful for my case, but I'm trying to find how to do it maybe with Regex.Replace

Comment: OP replaces only a1, b2, c1 and d2.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `tabs` instead of `spaces` in your replacement string, e. g. in

```
    Replace("a1", " a1 ")
```

is probably a `tab` (or 2 `tabs`) in the string `" a1 "` (which you don't see - so delete them and write them again and with `space` key in your keyboard).

Comment: No, seems like something wrong here, I have no any sorting there, and it works proper with replacing of characters and marks but with white-space I exactly this result

Comment: If you inspect your output file with a hex viewer what symbols do you see? (`Space` is `20`, `tab` is `09`, maybe you see other symbols.)

Comment: BTW is it OK that in your code one command have 2 `;` at the end and the previous no one?

Comment: no that was a bad cut, sorry, edited, because I got more values there, to make it shorter